# Passing multiple parameters in an MVC Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters

I am using an Ajax.ActionLink to call an Action in a Controller, nothing special there.  I want to pass two parameters to the Action.  Is this possible using an Ajax.ActionLink?  I thought that it would just be a matter of including multiple values in the AjaxOptions:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text",
    "ActionName",
    "ControllerName",
    new { firstParameter = firstValueToPass, secondParameter = secondValueToPass },
    new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "updateTargetId"} )%>
```

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters?

Where is a good place to learn more about the AjaxOptions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Depending on which overload you choose for Ajax.ActionLink, the parameter called `routeData` can contain an anonymous dictionary for the various parameters that will be passed to the action:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text",
    "DoSomething",
    "AwesomeController",
    new { foo = "foo1", bar = "bar1" },
    new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "updateTargetId"} )%>
```

This doesn't have anything to do with the `AjaxOptions` parameter, which gives you some control about the behavior of the request/response.

```
public class AwesomeController
{
   public ActionResult DoSomething(string foo, string bar)
   {
      /* return your content */
   }
}
```

Comment: How to generate path like `AwesomeController/DoSomething/foo1/bar1` instead of `AwesomeController/DoSomething?foo=foo1&bar=bar1`

Comment: How to generate path like this AwesomeController/DoSomething/foo1/bar1