# Passing parameters to MVC Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, parameters, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

How can I send the value of the TextBox as a parameter of the ActionLink?

I need to use the Html.TextBoxFor

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeField)%>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", "MyController", new { foo = "I need here the content of the textBox, I mean the 'SomeField' value"}, new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "updateTargetId"} )%>
```

The Contoller/Actions looks like this:

```
public class MyController{
   public ActionResult MyAction(string foo)
   {      
      /* return your content */   
   }
}
```

Using MVC 2.0

Comment: Your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595830/passing-multiple-parameters-in-an-mvc-ajax-actionlink

Answer (score 7):

> How can I send the value of the TextBox as a parameter of the ActionLink?

The semantically correct way of sending input fields values (such as textboxes) to a server is by using an html `<form>` and not links:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updateTargetId" })) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeField) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Link Text" />
<% } %>
```

Now in your controller action you will automatically get the value of the `SomeField` input entered by the user:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(string someField)
    {      
       /* return your content */   
    }
}
```

You could of course try to violate the markup semantics and the way HTML is supposed to work by insisting on using an `ActionLink` even if it is wrong. In this case here's what you could do:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeField) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { id = "myLink" }) %>
```

and then in a separate javascript file unobtrusively AJAXify this link using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        var value = $('#SomeField').val();
        $('#updateTargetId').load(this.href, { someField: value });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, why do you use the  $(function () { ? Why not the $('#myLink').click direclty? Is $(document).on('click', '#myLink', function () the same thing? Thanks